# make array of part of other array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

So I'm working on collecting a lot of data from a Gravity Forms form, which stores the values in array called $entry[].

I need to gather all the values from $entry[14] through $entry[30] or something around that. Is there a way to do a foreach loop or something for only those selected parts of the array?

my current solution is rather repetitive.

```
$valuesArray = array($entry["14"], $entry["15"], $entry["16"], $entry["17"], $entry["18"], $entry["19"]);
```

Var dump of $entry gives the following

```
array(30) { 
["id"]=> string(2) "48" 
["form_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["date_created"]=> string(19) "2016-10-27 13:30:24" 
["is_starred"]=> int(0) 
["is_read"]=> int(0) 
["ip"]=> string(13) "..." 
["source_url"]=> string(26) "http://examplesite.com/" 
["post_id"]=> NULL 
["currency"]=> string(3) "DKK" 
["payment_status"]=> NULL 
["payment_date"]=> NULL 
["transaction_id"]=> NULL 
["payment_amount"]=> NULL 
["payment_method"]=> NULL 
["is_fulfilled"]=> NULL 
["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" 
["transaction_type"]=> NULL 
["user_agent"]=> string(82) "" 
["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
[9]=> string(14) "Jeg er en mand" 
[10]=> string(9) "50-54 år" 
[11]=> string(9) "Kommune 3" 
[16]=> string(1) "3" 
[15]=> string(1) "0" 
[6]=> string(0) "" 
[1]=> string(0) "" 
[8]=> string(0) "" 
[12]=> string(0) "" 
[2]=> string(0) "" 
[5]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-chunk.php and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php

Comment: also [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php  also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mix of functions, avoiding loops:

```
$keys = array_flip(range(14,30));
$result = array_intersect_key($entry, $keys);
```

[`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) generates an array with the indices you want to compare against.
[`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) turns the so generated array **values** into  array **keys**, since you want to intersect array keys.
[`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) does what you need basically.

The above example could be written also as oneliner, but... you know readability and that ;)

Comment: This works like a charm too, thank you! Is it generally faster using functions rather than loops? Depending on the situation and amount of data of course.

Comment: yes, it's generally preferred to use [those functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) instead of loops for better performance

Answer (score 1):

You want to get `$entry[14]` through `$entry[30]`?

A `for` loop in PHP can run between a range of numbers and could work:

```
$newarray = array();
for ($x = 14; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    //The number is $x;
    $newarray[] = $entry[$x];
}
```

Comment: Jesus, that was fast. Works like a charm, thanks a lot! I have never really understood the for loop, but this make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure, using Array_Slice is probs the easiest solution here:

```
$originalArray = $entry; //Example just to show what original array is
$startOffset = 14;
$newArray = array_slice($originalArray, $startOffset);
```

You can also give it an ending offset (aka length)

```
$newArray = array_slice($originalArray, $startOffset, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen answer above, you also can use array_filter()

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <30; $i++)
{
  $array[$i] = $i;
}
$filtered = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($key){
        return $key > 13;
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
var_dump($filtered);
```

here is the [demo](https://eval.in/667843)